# Are those names the same? Shuppim and Huppim - Shupham and Hupham - Shephuphan and Huram - Muppim and Huppim

Tags: genesis, numbers, genealogy, 1-chronicles, name

The following names are said to be the same by some, and sometimes two or three of them are the same person, and the resources and dictionaries vary a lot.  I read [an article](https://www.biblicalcyclopedia.com/S/shuppim.html) mentioning them, but I can't understand their take in the matter.

Any idea about those people? If they are the same, *how*? And if they are different, *why* many resources merge them as the same brothers?

- **Muppim and Huppim** (Ge 46:21): sons of Benjamin
- **Shupham and Hupham** (Nu 26:39): posterity of Benjamin
- **Shuppim and Huppim** (1Ch 7:12): sons of Ir
- **Shephuphan and Huram** (1Ch 8:5): sons of Bela

Comment: Up-voted +1. Thank you for moving it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer (and there are many long answers in the literature) is that, it is possible that these are all referring to the same two people.  The reason is simple as the Cambridge commentary observes for Gen 46:21:

> 21. the sons of Benjamin] The mention of Benjamin’s sons in a list purporting to be a record of those who came with Jacob into Egypt is
>     of course irreconcilable with the narrative. But it illustrates the
>     separate origin of these lists of names (connected with P) from the
>     general narrative preserved by J and E. The difficulty experienced by
>     the ordinary reader was possibly felt in very early times. The LXX
>     gives Benjamin three sons, Bela, Chobor, and Ashbel; six grandsons,
>     sons of Bela, viz. Gera, Naaman, Ehi, Rosh, Muppim, and Huppim; and
>     one great-grandson, Ard, the son of Gera. If this list was the
>     original form of the genealogy, it may have been modified, in order to
>     get rid of the strange statement, that Benjamin’s grandsons and
>     great-grandsons went down with Jacob into Egypt. Another version is
>     given in Numbers 26:38-40.

Thus, the record of Benjamin's progeny is clearly from a later time to round out the record.  Thus, Huppim and Muppim (both plural in form) are likely decedents rather than sons as the later records show.

Comment: The idea of lists being "modified" at a later date is not acceptable as a means of explaining things, as it contradicts: "All Scripture is given by inspiration of God" (2 Timothy 3:16).  If Moses *himself* is the one who modified the list for a certain reason, that's another thing that needs to be explained.

Comment: @Mike - it is certainly possible that Mosses added the later data.  However, when Jacob's family, including Benjamin moved to Egypt as recorded in Gen 46, Benjamin was to young to have children much less grandchildren.